# Checking whether a density is exponential family

Tags: self-study, density-function, exponential-family

Trying to prove that this doesn't belong to exponential family.

$f(y|a)=4\frac{(y+a)}{(1+4a)} ;  0 < y < 1 , a>0$

Here is my approach:

$$f(y|a) = 4(y+a)e^{-log(1+4a)}$$
$$f(y|a) = (4y)(1+\frac{a}{y})e^{-log(1+4a)}$$

Comparing it with standard form, $h(y) = 4y$ and $g(a)$ which has to be a function of only $a$, can not be defined in terms of $a$ alone, as $y$ in the $1+\frac{a}{y}$ is inseparable. Is this enough to show that this distribution doesn't belong to exponential family.

Please review my approach.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've put your finger on the crux of the matter, and indeed the result is fairly obvious, but the logic seems a little off.  The method described below repeatedly uses logarithms and differentiation to make the problem progressively simpler, until it becomes utterly trivial.

---

By definition, $f$ is the PDF for an exponential family when its logarithm can be written as a sum of something in terms of the parameter ($a$) only, something else in terms of the data ($y$) only, and something else that is a product of a function of $a$ and a function of $y$.  This means you are free to ignore any factors that clearly depend only on the parameter or only on the data.  In this case it's obvious $\frac{4}{1+4a}$ depends only on $a$, so we may ignore it.

The issue is with $y+a$.  We need to prove there cannot exist "nice" functions $\eta$ and $T$ such that $\log(y+a) = \eta(a) T(y)$ plus some function of $a$ alone plus some other function of $y$ alone.  That "plus" part is annoying, but we can kill it off by differentiating first with respect to $a$ (the derivative of any function of $y$ alone will be zero) and then with respect to $y$ (the derivative of a function of $a$ alone will be zero).  Upon negating both sides (to make the left hand side positive) this gives

$$-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial a\partial y}\log(y+a) = \frac{1}{(a+y)^2} = -\eta'(a)T'(y).$$

I want to take logarithms to simplify the right hand side (which, being equal to the left hand side, is always positive).  Assuming $\eta'$ and $T'$ are both continuous will guarantee there are some intervals of values for $a$ and for $y$ in which either $-\eta'(a)\gt 0$ and $T'(y)\gt 0$ or else $\eta'(a)\gt 0$ and $-T'(y)\gt 0$.  This means we indeed can split the right hand side into two positive factors, allowing the logarithm to be applied.  Doing so yields

$$-2\log(a+y) = \log\frac{1}{(a+y)^2} =  \log\left(-\eta'(a)T'(y)\right) = \log(-\eta'(a)) + \log(T'(y))$$

(or else a comparable expression with a few minus signs thrown in).  Now we play the same game: in either case, differentiating both sides with respect to both $a$ and $y$ yields

$$\frac{2}{(a+y)^2} = 0,$$

an impossibility.

Looking back, this approach had to assume both $\eta$ and $T$ have second derivatives within some intervals of their arguments.  The analysis can be done along the same lines using finite differences to weaken those assumptions, but it's probably not worth the bother.

Comment: My notation is that of Wikipedia, which also lists [a set of rules for identifying exponential families.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family#Factorization_of_the_variables_involved). The methods illustrated here can be used to justify those rules.

Comment: Beautiful analysis; the use of mixed second partial derivatives is somewhat reminiscent of criteria to check whether functions are "nomogramable", at least of particular forms (which also involves a similar separation).

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b. It is also more than reminiscent of analysis of interactions in two-way tables. That's the finite-differences version. ;-)

Comment: Yes; that, too, is a connection I've exploited in playing with nomograms.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your explanation. But I am finding hard time to understand why are we taking partial derivatives and taking log again. Is there a possibility that this be solved by defining an indicator function for y which would always depend on a.

Comment: I did make an effort to explain the reasons: taking partial derivatives removes univariate additive terms and taking logarithms simplifies products into sums. I am at a loss to find another way to re-state those reasons. Perhaps re-reading my answer would help you understand. I haven't any idea what an "indicator function for $y$" would mean: indicators correspond to *subsets of the domain of a function,* whereas $y$ merely represents an element of the open interval $(0,1)$.

Comment: @whuber Thank you! I appreciate your detailed response; I had one problem where I used indicator function, but that case was totally different(where value of y depend on a). I am able to follow it now!

Comment: @whuber You said that this approach assumes that 2nd derivative exists. Is it because we want to contradict what we assumed, or are we assuming that the 2nd derivative of the complete function exists(one wrt $a$ and other wrt $y$, which makes sense). In general a polynomial of degree 1 would have only 1st derivative and all others would be zero. I followed your approach completely now, but this point related to 2nd derivative is not clear.

Comment: @whuber Shouldn't we be proving log(y+a)=η(a)T(y), since some function of a alone is $\frac{1}{(1+4a)}$ and some other function of $y$ alone is $4I(y)$, where $I(y)$ exists from $0<y<1$.Please correct me if I am interpreting it wrongly

Comment: You can't overlook the possibility that $\log(y+a)=\eta(a)T(y)$ *plus* some other stuff. Just because you have ignored a factor of $1/(1+4a)$ does not mean it was the *right* factor to ignore and that by ignoring it only $\eta(a)T(y)$ (plus some function only of $y$) is all that's left of the logarithm. That's the logical difficulty I refer to at the outset.

Answer (score 1):

It will be in exponential family if it can be written in $fh(x)e^{ηT(x)-A(η)}$(with another conditions ) .

Let $g(x,η)=ηT(x)-A(η)$. Now for any 4 data points $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ in the sample space
$ \frac{(g(x1,η)-g(x2,η))}{(g(x3,η)-g(x4,η))}$= $\frac{(T(x1)-T(x2))}{(T(x3) - T(x4))}$ , which is free of η.

Now here $f(y;a)= 4\frac{y+a}{(4a+1)}$ = $4 e^( ln(y+a)-ln(4a+1) )$.
Take $g(x,η)=ln(y+a)-ln(4a+1)$.

So
$\frac{(g(x1,η)-g(x2,η))}{(g(x3,η)-g(x4,η))}$=$\frac{(ln(y1+a)-ln(y2+a))}{(ln(y3+a)-ln(y4+a))}$
- which is not free of a .
so $f(y;a)$ does not belong to Exponential family .

Comment: +1 I like the straightforward approach.  It clearly indicates how finite differences can be used to isolate the key behavior of $f$.